# Как выбирать случайные фотографии без повторов?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

В общем, есть код, он выгружает в бота фоточки рандомные с папки, нужно сделать так чтоб рандомные фотки не повторялись

```
def start(message):
  if message.text == 'Фото':
      photo = open('test/' + random.choice(os.listdir('test')), 'rb')
      bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo)
```

если такое вообще возможно

Comment: сделай массив фоток. Из массива делаем рандом. Удаляем из массива рандом

Comment: вопросик должен иметь толковый заголовочек, а не вот это вот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте класс, там массив, с именем допустим `sended_photos`.
Дальше гененируйте рандомное фото из папки, и если такое есть в `sended_photos`, то ре-генерируем и отправляем, добавляем в массив, если такого нет в массиве, то добавляем фото в массив и отправляем.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, добавлять photo в список, и если оно там есть - пропускать.

Comment: Не сработает...

Comment: очень много фоток(